# Order of column keys in Bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I'm using Bigtable for a project I'm working on and I've been assuming the column keys in a column family are ordered lexicographically.

Just to reassure my assumptions, I'd like to confirm the column keys within a column family are guaranteed to be ordered lexicographically by the column key when retrieved from Bigtable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rowkeys in Cloud Bigtable sorted Lexicographically](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#time_series_and_title_short).

Column Qualifiers - are as well.